# Deleting a server file

Tags: php, file, delete-file

I'm looking for a way to delete a file from the server using PHP. Basically I have my files listed on a page in this manner:

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="delete_file.php?file=uploads/file_01.jpg">Delete File 01</a></li>
    <li><a href="delete_file.php?file=uploads/file_02.jpg">Delete File 02</a></li>
    <li><a href="delete_file.php?file=uploads/file_03.jpg">Delete File 03</a></li>
</ul>
```

The problem is I'm not sure how to get my delete_file.php file to work. I believe it needs to be something like this:

```
<?php 
    $path="uploads/file_01.jpg";
    if(unlink($path)) echo "File Deleted"; 
?>
```

...but I'm not sure how to get the $path to change to the file I had clicked on to delete.

Comment: you want $_GET['file'], and this is insane as i could add a file to the url ande delete it.

Comment: What if someone pass `delete_file.php?file=delete_file.php`?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

while you have to be incredibly careful with giving a user the ability to delete files, I'll give you enough rope to hang yourself

define a base directory that will contain any files that will be deleted

```
$base_directory = '/home/myuser/';
```

Then delete the file

```
if(unlink($base_directory.$_GET['file']))
    echo "File Deleted.";
```

Comment: Thanks for that. Worked a treat. You mean disallow directory browsing?

Comment: what if somebody passes this URL: `/delete_file.php?file=../../etc/passwd`

Comment: @user606263 no, jnpcl means to not allow someone to post `file=../../etc/apache2/apach2.conf` that would, given the right permissions, delete the configuration file for the web server part of your server

Comment: @Patrick - gotcha. Shouldn't be an issue as the script can't be executed unless you're logged in as an administrator (me).

Answer (score 5):

```
<?php
  $file_to_delete = $_GET['file'];
  if (is_file($file_to_delete)){
    echo (unlink($file_to_delete) ? "File Deleted" : "Problem deleting file";

  }
?>
```

I'm not going to lie, don't know a better way to sanitize the $_GET['file'] other than check if it's a file. If this isn't a valid way, experts please chime in. (Maybe follow the guidelines [present in this SO topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/456546/how-do-i-make-sure-a-file-path-is-within-a-given-subdirectory)?)

Comment: the amount of sanitizing that you would have to do to protect yourself would be ridiculous with this functionality given to any end-user.  So I'll leave that to the OP :-)

Comment: Clean it with [`basename()`](http://php.net/basename) to keep the person from entering something like `../../someotherfile`.

Comment: another small prbolem, you forgot `)` before the `;` on line where is `echo`, but everything other is fine

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes you may want to create the path dynamically.

For example, I am using a CMS in different places therefore I should not use fixed definitions.

My project structure:

-myProject 
|-admin 
|--app 
|---controllers 
|-upload

```
$base_directory = dirname(__FILE__);
echo $base_directory; //'/home/myProject/public_html/admin/app/controlers/'
```

This is taking the path to the running php file.

My php file in `'admin/app/controllers/'`

But upload file in `'upload/'`

We need to delete unnecessary directories for the correct path. The file in the upload folder so we dont need to 'admin/app/controllers/' is unnecessary. So we are removing this part.

```
$path = str_replace('admin/app/controllers/', '', $path);
echo $path;  //'/home/myProject/public_html/upload/myFile'
```

Now we have correct path and we can delete the file.

```
if (file_exists($path)){
    if(unlink($path)){
       echo "File deleted";
    }
}else{
     echo "File is not exists";
}
```