# Perl / CGI: redirect to a different page after downloading a file

Tags: perl, redirect, cgi, download

this is quite a newbie question and I've searched on this topic for a while, but nothing I've found seems to work as described. I have this piece of code, for providing a file download to the user, which works perfectly:

```
open(DOC, "<$file_name") or die "$!";
@textFile = <DOC>;  
close DOC;

print "Content-Type:application/x-download\n";  
print "Content-Disposition:attachment;filename=" . $basename . "\n\n";   
print @textFile;
```

My problem is that after the file-download has started, I would like to redirect the user to a different page. The script above is actually being submitted from a form by another script where I have:

```
<form action="/cgi-bin/download.pl">   
    <p> some msg </p>  
    <p><input type="submit" value="Download" name="Download"></p>            
    </form>
```

I've tried putting some javascript statements in the input-Tag like:

```
onclick="javascript:window.document.location.href=\'http://www.mynewpage.com'
```

as well as printing at the end (of download.pl) something like:

```
print "Location: http://www.mynewpage.com";
```

It doesn't work.

If someone could give me a hint, I'd really appreciate that!

Thanks in advance!

Alex

Answer (score 1):

You cannot do this with HTTP (see ADW's resposne).

What most sites do is to redirect you to a page which has some javascript which then *starts* the download. It also provides a link in case that doesn't work.

For example:  http://sourceforge.net/projects/sevenzip/files/7-Zip/9.22/7z922.exe/download

See this SO question about the javascript: [starting file download with JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/365777/starting-file-download-with-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

You can't do it using straight http/html.

The response to the query is a file, you're not allowed to send an additional response (i.e. a redirect) as well.

As Dave says, normally it's done with JavaScript.