# how can I create and download the html file using clientside(javascript) code?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is possible to create and download as .html file using jquery/javascript?

If not, is any third party website API available?

Because I planed to create a prototype maker through in blogger.com.

There I can write only client side program.

Answer (score 2):

You can try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7271524/how-to-download-the-current-page-as-a-file-attachment-using-javascript) may help you.

```
<div id="test">
    <span>testing</span>
</div>

(function(){
    document.location = 
        'data:text/attachment;,' + //here is the trick
        document.getElementById('test').innerHTML;
            //document.documentElement.innerHTML; //To Download Entire Html Source
})();
```

You can also use html5

```
<a href="javascript:$('#test').html();" download="Filename">Download Div</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the $http.get method? That should return a html page (or anything else for that matter). You haven't really said what you want to do with it though...

https://api.jquery.com/jquery.get/

Comment: I've just re-read your question - creating a HTML file and uploading it to a server isn't going to be possible without some server side code. Getting an existing file will be possible with the get method.