# How to make a web page editable in real-time and save locally?

Tags: javascript, html, css, real-time, offline

I have a basic .html file i use for my homepage, it has links to various websites i visit with html and some css

Im looking to make it editable in real-time (in the browser) and making it save automatically directly to the .html file

not sure where to start?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Editable_content

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. [Read here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for more information about how to create a Minimal, Complete and Verifiable question.

Comment: Browser don't have the ability to edit html and save it automatically since that's usually not required, and may even be a security flaw. You'll need to send requests to a server that saves the modified page.

Answer (score 1):

Try in console on any page:

```
document.documentElement.contentEditable = true;
```

Comment: This doesn't save automatically to a HTML file though.

Comment: It's true. Use AJAX for sending data to server, for example, see http://jsfiddle.net/ch6yn/

Comment: The question said **locally** not "on a remote server".

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to *automatically* save an HTML page to the client ***locally***. However, it is possible to let the user download the current page, say, by clicking a button that says "Download." See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7271524/how-to-download-the-current-page-as-a-file-attachment-using-javascript?answertab=active#tab-top) for an example of the implementation.

However, if you want to save it to the server, you can do that using AJAX requests. You will need a server-side implementation of this, not just static HTML, though.