# How to download / save the content of a HTML page generated with PHP?

Tags: javascript, php, html

I'm generating a HTML / Javascript page using PHP.

I'd like to offer to my users, after the preview of the page, the chance to save / download, programmatically (not interactively using browser functionalities ....), the code of this HTML / Javascript page.

I've tried to search on the web for any examples but nothing appears.

Any suggestion / example? Thank you very much in advance!

Cesare

Comment: I think PHP is kind of irrelevant here; the process would be the same regardless of where the page came from.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to download the current page as a file / attachment using Javascript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7271524/how-to-download-the-current-page-as-a-file-attachment-using-javascript)

Comment: ok "not exactly" what I need but useful. The sample in that post download the "body" content of the HTML page not the "all" HTML / Javascript code page

Comment: Oh, I thought it looked like the commented out part in the accepted answer would get the entire page. Does it not?

Comment: Just tested and like the answer said using`document.documentElement.innerHTML` downloads the entire page (head and body) doesn't it for you? Try maybe with `outerHTML`.

Comment: I've tried to use the commented row but something goes wrong when I use it with my page. Anyway using the commented line you download ALL the code, so also the javascript at the end of the page and this is .... too much. I've tried with the HTML code in the sample ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved using the solution shown in this post ...

https://thiscouldbebetter.wordpress.com/2012/12/18/loading-editing-and-saving-a-text-file-in-html5-using-javascrip/

I've put my code in a variable and then show it in the text area.

It's working !!