# Append a iframe to a div by prototype.js

Tags: prototypejs

I am using prototype.js.I want to append a I-frame on a click on Div.for this I am using following code.

```
//JS Code
Event.observe(window, 'load', function()
{ $('test').observe('click', function()
  {
    $('d1').update ('<iframe src="http://www.abc.com" width="100%" height="300px;" border="0" id="myframe"></iframe>');
   Effect.toggle('d1','slide'); return false;
  });
});
```

This is working fine but the problem is that I want to show loading image before rendering the iframe and image will be hide when iframe loaded completely.
For this I want to call a callback function.but I don't have any idea about this.
Please help me how can I do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one way:

JavaScript:

```
Event.observe('test', 'click', function(event) {
    $('d1').addClassName('loading').update('<iframe src="http://www.abc.com/" width="100%" height="1" border="0" id="myframe" onload="this.setAttribute(\'height\', 300);$(\'d1\').removeClassName(\'loading\')"></iframe>');
    event.stop();
});​​
```

HTML:

```
<a href="#" id="test">Test</a>

<div id="d1"></div>​
```

Some CSS:

```
#d1 {
   height: 300px;
   background-color: #ccc;
}
#d1.loading {
   background-color: #c00;
   /* put your background loading image as a background-image here */
}
```

​

Comment: yes dude!this is the way.I have already in this way.I have called a java script function onload attribue of iframe as you have done.
):

Comment: This solution only worked for me in FF. I realized I had problems with headers, so this solution worked for me at the end
http://stackoverflow.com/a/4646947/318380