# Chrome not working for window.open?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, google-chrome, firefox

I am trying to show a download pop up to the user which is an ajax call giving text/csv formatted response.

The issue: it's working well in Firefox but not in Chrome, where it's opening a new tab. This is definitely unintended, and I would prefer it didn't happen. Any ideas on what I could change...?

```
function x() {

  var obj = jQuery("input:checked").map(function() 
  { 
    return jQuery(this).parents('tr').attr('id'); 
  });

  var result = null;
  var arr = jQuery.makeArray(obj);
  var data = arr.join(',');

  $.ajax({
    url : '<%= url_for :controller => "liges", :action => "export_to_csv" %>',
    type : 'POST',
    data : {data:data},
    dataType : 'string',
    async: false,
    success : function(response) { 
      window.open('data:text/csv;charset=utf-8,'+escape(response)); 
    }    
  }); 
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
window.open("","","width=400,height=150");
```

By the way chrome will block popup windows on page, until you give him access.

Comment: With this, tab is not opening. Its showing me a pop up window. But still that is not a download pop, as the code does in FF

Comment: and yeah I enabled the pop ups from the settings!!

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass `_blank` as another parameter:

**From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.open):**

> To open a new window on every call of `window.open()`, use the special value `_blank` for `strWindowName`.

**Example:**

```
window.open('data:text/csv;charset=utf-8,'+escape(response), '_blank');
```

Comment: _blank did not help. It showing me the same stuff!! a new tab with all the csv content as html.

Comment: so you don't have any pop-up blockers running?

Comment: how about thinking of a different way to display the csv, most users will have pup-up blockers in any case, try sending the content to a hidden `iframe` to start the download, or display it in a `div`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/365777/starting-file-download-with-javascript here is the iframe example i found..but will this way work with rails..??? in that case, in the path i need to provide the controller and action??