# How to download file from local directory using python

Tags: django, python-3.x

I want to download a file from the local directory when the user clicks on a particular link. How I can do it using python.

Comment: "when user clicks on perticular link it goes to correct location but file does not download" what does happen? what type of file?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [starting file download with JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/365777/starting-file-download-with-javascript)

Comment: I have used whoosh library for indexing . I have around 900 files which are stored in static>datasets>documents directory.  I get error as - The requested URL /static/documents/dataset/dynamic.ppt was not found on this server.

Comment: so it doesn't go to the correct file, looks like you found the issue then

Comment: The path I found is correct but it does not download.

Comment: if you have the error "The requested URL /static/documents/dataset/dynamic.ppt was not found on this server." then how can the file path be correct? where is that error coming from?

Comment: see my files are stored in this location - static/documents/dataset/dynamic.ppt and error is coming as The requested URL /static/documents/dataset/dynamic.ppt was not found. if you observe here both path are same.

Comment: its unclear what your asking, it certainly doesn't seem to be a javascript problem

Answer (score 0):

Try this on click of link:

```
location.replace('your_loacal_filepath')
```

For Example:

```
location.replace('/files/out.txt')
```

Comment: I didnt get your point but I used as - <a href="'+ location.replace("xy") +'" target="_blank" >' even it does not work

Answer (score 0):

if you are rendering HTML, then you should read about the [HTML download Attribute](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_a_download.asp)

*Quoting*

> The download attribute specifies that the target will be downloaded when a user clicks on the hyperlink.
>
> This attribute is only used if the href attribute is set.

```
else if(currentobj.filename != null){
   var xy = '{% static "/documents/dataset/" %}' + currentobj.filename;
   alert(xy);
   var $tr = $('<tr><td style="padding:5px;"><a href="'+ xy +'" 
                 target="_blank" download>' + currentobj.filename.slice(0,25) + 
                 "....." +'</a></td> </tr>');
   $tbl.append($tr);
  }
```

just add `download` tag along the hyperlink

if you want to specify a specific name for the download file then just mention it like this

```
<a href="/images/myw3schoolsimage.jpg" download="w3logo">
```

Comment: I have 900 files then how I can use  download="w3logo"

Comment: can you explain please if there is error message or any clue ??

Comment: I m working on chatbot where I got multiple results when user click on perticular link it will be downloaded. I have two functions , first function I have given server link that will work . but it does not work for local directory . I got error as -The requested URL  static/documents/dataset/dynamic.ppt was not found but file path is correct.

Comment: did you try to substitute the link in the `href` tag with an online url to a file, instead of using local one ?? and see what happens ...like for example use this photo and see the errors that is going to appear `https://www.w3schools.com/images/myw3schoolsimage.jpg`

Comment: I have tried instead of local directory when I pass server url it works.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this.

The download attribute instructs browsers to download a URL instead of navigating to it.
Check out. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a#Attributes